# Why I cannot compare date using ">" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL to filter the date according to the **CreationDate**.

If I did this without comparing the **CreationDate**, it will return some results.

```
    use todo;
    SELECT *
    FROM ToDoItem
    WHERE ToDoListID = 1
    AND COMPLETED = 1
    AND Priority>=2;
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgI90.jpg)

However, when I add the comparison with date, there will be no result.

```
    use todo;
    SELECT *
    FROM ToDoItem
    WHERE ToDoListID = 1
    AND COMPLETED = 1
    AND Priority>=2
    AND CreationDate > ´2004-11-18 15:26:58´;
```

[No Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5pIM.jpg)

It says there is a "SQL syntax error near '15:26:58' " and the "query interrupted".

I do not why this does not work because I saw some examples on stackoverflow using ">" and "<" to compare two date directly.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: instead of posting pics, try http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use single quotes (`'`) instead of backticks (`), so your query should be:

```
use todo;
    SELECT *
    FROM ToDoItem
    WHERE ToDoListID = 1
    AND COMPLETED = 1
    AND Priority>=2
    AND CreationDate > '2004-11-18 15:26:58';
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! This solves my problem. I am using the VirtualBox and I did not notice this.

Answer (score 0):

To get reliable results, you should use `DATEDIFF()`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ToDoItem
  WHERE ToDoListID = 1
    AND COMPLETED = 1
    AND Priority>=2
    AND DATEDIFF(CreationDate, '2004-11-18 15:26:58') > 0;
```

`DATEDIFF(Expr1, Expr2)` returns >0 if `Expr1` is after `Expr2`, and <0 if `Expr1` is before `Expr2`.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this function!

Comment: `CreationDate > '2004-11-18 15:26:58'` is unreliable?

Comment: Interesting, but unnecessary here: the query performance will suffer (functions are bad for sargability), and comparing dates is possible using `<` `>` operators.